# Populating MVC 5 View ComboBox using Javascript based on another ComboBox selection

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core MVC web project and I want to populate values of ComboBox B (Churches) based on selection of ComboBox A (Stations) using JavaScript (Json). I have tried to research with no success.
Here are my codes:

MVC View Code:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RSTATIONID" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Station:</label>
                <div id="station" class="col-sm-8">
                    <select asp-for="RSTATIONID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RSTATIONID"
                            onchange="LoadChurches(this)"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="RSTATIONID" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="RCHURCHID" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Church:</label>
                <div id="church" class="col-sm-8">
                    <select asp-for="RCHURCHID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RCHURCHID"></select>
                    <span asp-validation-for="RCHURCHID" class="text-danger" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript Code:

```js
function LoadChurches(e) {
    var stationID = e.value;
    //alert(stationID);
    $.ajax
   ({
       url: '/CaptureReceipts/LoadChurches',
       type: 'POST',
       datatype: 'application/json',
       contentType: 'application/json',
       data: JSON.stringify({
           stationID: +stationID
       }),
       success: function (result) {
           var res = result.value;
           alert(JSON.stringify(res));
           /*$("#church").html("");
           $.each($.parseJSON(result), function (i, church) {
               SetSel(this);
           }); */
       },
       error: function () {
           alert("Churches can not load"); 
       } 
   });
}
```

Controller Code:

```
 public JsonResult LoadChurches(string statID)
    {
        int stationID = Convert.ToInt32(statID);
        var churches = new SelectList(_context.v_Church.Where(m => m.StationID == stationID), "ID", "churchName");                    
        return Json(ViewData);
    }
```

The Controller name is CaptureReceiptsController. Please help me know what may be wrong.

Comment: Do you get any error in application? Or check the browser's inspect window, in the console tab if there is any error. If there is, then add it to your question.

Comment: Well, you should return churches and not ViewData.

Comment: No, I wasn't getting any errors. But the churches were not being loaded.

Comment: Because you are loading churches in 'churches' variable but you are not returning it. instead  you are returning ViewData --> return Json(ViewData)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller return simple json array:

```
var churches = _context.v_Church
                  .Where(m => m.StationID == stationID)
                  .Select(x => new {id = x.ID, name = x.churchName })
                  .ToArray();
return JSON(churches);
```

In `success` callback:

```
success: function (data) {
    var churchSelect = $("#church > select")
    churchSelect.html(""); //clear select
    for (var i =0;i<data.length;i++){
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.innerHTML = data[i].name;
        opt.value = data[i].id;
        churchSelect.append(opt);
    }
}
```